# aws lambda update-function-configuration has no --profile option?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Am i missing something ? it seems that you can use --profile with almost any other aws cli functionality.

is there any other way around this then by manually running aws configure ?

Comment: You can pass --profile with all aws commands. What's the error you receive when you try it?

Comment: i figured it out - i needed to pass the --profile switch as the first argument for whatever reason

Comment: That's not true. The placement of the parameter does not matter.

Comment: you're right. i had a bug in my bash script that was calling this function

Answer (score 0):

update Lambda environment variables from JSON file

aws lambda update-function-configuration --profile mfa --function-name test-api --cli-input-json file://dev.json